# Issues while Streaming rtsp video on Raspberry Pi4 using VLC Library

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, monodevelop, rtsp, libvlcsharp

I am developing an app in C# and running it through mono on raspberry pi4. This app will play the RTSP stream on the form and also I need to capture the image out the video.

I am using the libVLCSharp library to stream the video. I am able to stream properly while running on windows but as soon as I run through mono it returns the following error and video is not played

```
[ac0508a0] main video output error: video output creation failed
[b10110c8] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[ac0508a0] main video output error: video output creation failed
```

Below is the code I am using

```
public LibVLC _libVLC;
public MediaPlayer _mp;
public Cam()
{
if (!DesignMode)
{
Core.Initialize();
}
InitializeComponent();
_libVLC = new LibVLC();
_mp = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
videoView1.MediaPlayer = _mp;
}

private void Cam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
_mp.Play(new Media(_libVLC, "rtsp://192.168.1.208:554/lp", FromType.FromLocation));
}
```

For Library reference

```
https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You didn't mentionned what gui library you are using, but I am assuming that you are trying to use WinForms. LibVLCSharp implementation for WinForms is only explicitely supported for Windows, because there was no demand and because we didn't know which bugs we would have to maintain on that platform.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I am using WinForms. Is there any way I can play the RTSP stream on a Raspberry pi through C# application build on windows and running through mono?

Comment: The only gui platform supported on linux at the moment is mono's gtk-sharp(see the docs), and its Xamarin.Forms implementation. It is also supported on windows, but you need to install gtk-sharp separately ( no NuGet)